# How to use the OAuth2 toolkit with the Django REST framework with class-based views?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, oauth2-toolkit

I'm trying to add an API using the [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to an existing codebase which uses the [Django OAuth2 toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The existing views make use of the fact that the OAuth2 toolkit's backend modifies the behavior of Django's `login_required` decorator so that it uses OAuth2 authentication. The function-based views look similar to the one in the tutorial example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

@login_required()
def secret_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse('Secret contents!', status=200)
```

I'm trying to adapt the example given on https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html to my situation, but I'm finding it's not an exact correspondence, because the example uses the DRF's `ModelViewSet` classes whereas my current view uses a (less-integrated) generic class-based view:

```
from rest_framework import generics

from ..models import Session
from ..serializers import SessionSerializer


class SessionDetail(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Session.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SessionSerializer
```

where I've set the default permission class to `IsAuthenticated` in `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
}
```

This should allow a `Session` object to be updated using PATCH requests, but it appears to return a `403 Forbidden` response for use cases similar to the ones for the current views decorated with `login_required`.

How can I update the `SessionDetail` view so that it behaves the same as a function view decorated with `login_required`? I suspect that I need to use the [TokenHasReadWriteScope](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/permissions.html#tokenhasreadwritescope) permission class, since this appears to be the only one for which the `required_scopes` is optional. (The views decorated with `login_required` don't provide `required_scopes` either).

Would it be like this:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import OAuth2Authentication, TokenHasReadWriteScope

from ..models import Session
from ..serializers import SessionSerializer


class SessionDetail(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [OAuth2Authentication]
    permission_classes = [TokenHasReadWriteScope]
    queryset = Session.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SessionSerializer
```

Also, would I have to update my `REST_FRAMEWORK` setting with a `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    )
}
```

Right now if I run the server and try to make a patch request with the browsable API, I get a `401 Unauthorized` error:

[image]

Also if I `Log in` using a username and password that I just created using `python manage.py createsuperuser`, it goes straight back to this `401` page instead of one with a form to make a PATCH request as I'd expect.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Try to add to `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` list `'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'` this will enable session authentication in browser.

Comment: Have you find the solution to your problem ?